# How can I define a base style.css file for a Django application

Tags: python, django

I am making a project in Django where I have multiple apps. For this project I defined a base.html where I have my navbar and my footer. Now I am looking to add a css file that would be available for all the apps for having a common background image.

What I ended up doing is making a static folder into the project folder however django is complaining that it can not get the static file from there. How can I manage this base style.css file?

My folder structure is like this:

```
--Project
   |-- Project
   |    |--static
   |       |--Project
   |           |--style.css
   |-- App1
   |-- App2
   |-- App3
```

My intention is to be able to use the style.css classes in App1, App2 and App3. The message that I get is that django can not collect the Project/style.css file because the ~/Project/Project/static folder does not exist.

Comment: Can you add the static file settings from your `settings.py`? and what path are you using to include the static file in your base.html?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say, the most common practice is to use a `common` app in your project.

Besides, there are probably other elements that you can share and factorize that way.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was what you mean but I managed to fix my problem. You mentioned having a common app but I realized that went against the fact that I had a base.html which was in the first level Project folder. So I moved the static folder a level up and that basically fixed it. Making it common for all other apps